# how to install apt-get packages on composer2 of GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm planning to use Composer2 as my airflow runtime.
To use my airflow script, I need to install chrome binary on the machine,
But I don't know how to execute 'apt-get install' command on my composer2 environment.

As I saw the document, it seems that Composer2 only supports the airflow commands, not linux commands.

Please let me know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to install binary on `Cloud Composer` machines is a connection on the `GKE` cluster where `Composer` is installed.

Then you can install on the `GKE` nodes the `chrome binary`.

From the `GKE` console, you can access to the cluster and connect into with the following command from your schell (you have to be authenticated with an authorized identity) :

```bash
gcloud container clusters get-credentials instance-name-gke --region europe-west1 --project your-project
```